# How to tell child modules to use specific logger

Tags: python-2.7

I have created two loggers in my logging module like logger1,logger2 and my application has two submodules module1 and module2.I want to configure/tell module1 should use logger1 and module2 should use logger2 only?

Answer (score 0):

Assign `logger1` to some variable in `module1` and let functions in that module use that variable to call correct logger. And remeber to check in functions whether variable is not `None`.

Comment: The following are my two loggers logger1 =logging.getLogger('log1'),logger2

Comment: logger1=logger.getLogger('log1'),logger2 = logger.getLogger('log2').These are my two loggers.To which i should assign variable,for logger1 or log1.could you give syntax how to assign variable in one module